# Cannot determine the drive of my USB Device

Tags: c++, winapi

I am writing a program to detect whenever a USB pen drive is inserted. On inserting the usb pen drive, it is detected as DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE but not as DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME. So I cannot get the volume drive letter(A,B, C, D,...) How can I solve this i.e. make it detectable as DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME or get the drive letter in some other way.

```
    LRESULT message_handler(HWND__* hwnd, UINT uint, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
    {
       switch (uint)
       {
case WM_NCCREATE: // before window creation
        return true;
        break;

    case WM_CREATE: // the actual creation of the window
    {
        // you can get your creation params here..like GUID..
        LPCREATESTRUCT params = (LPCREATESTRUCT)lparam;
        GUID InterfaceClassGuid = *((GUID*)params->lpCreateParams);
        DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE NotificationFilter;
        ZeroMemory(&NotificationFilter, sizeof(NotificationFilter));
        NotificationFilter.dbcc_size = sizeof(DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE);
        NotificationFilter.dbcc_devicetype = DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE;
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(GuidDevInterfaceList); i++) {
            NotificationFilter.dbcc_classguid = GuidDevInterfaceList[i];

            HDEVNOTIFY dev_notify = RegisterDeviceNotification(hwnd, &NotificationFilter, DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE);
            if (dev_notify == NULL) {     // Handle the error by returning correct error in LRESULT format and remove throw...   
                throw std::runtime_error("Could not register for device Notifications!");
            }
        }

    }
    break;

        case WM_DEVICECHANGE:
        {

            PDEV_BROADCAST_HDR lpdb = (PDEV_BROADCAST_HDR)lparam;   

                                        //DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME
            if (lpdb->dbch_devicetype == DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE)
            {

                switch (wparam)
                {

                case DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL: 
                {                   
                    cout<<"Device Arrived"<<endl;

                }
    }}}}}
```

It detects that a device is inserted

OUTPUT:

```
Device Arrived
Failed
```

Comment: `dbch_devicetype == DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE` so of course it can not be `DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME`

Comment: That is the problem.  My my pendrive is detected as DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE and not as  DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME.

Comment: Then why do you have a test for an impossible thing, and expect it to work? What are you trying to do? What does the documentation say?

Comment: I have corrected the question..

Comment: when you inside `if (lpdb->dbch_devicetype == DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE)` check for `(lpdb->dbch_devicetype == DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME)` this of course is problem. in code logic. you really need `RegisterDeviceNotification` with `GUID_DEVINTERFACE_VOLUME` register (how you register not visible)

Comment: for what you need volume drive letter ? you have volume name

Comment: I want to detect the inserted device uses which drive letter then perform some operations on it

Comment: why exactly drive letter ? (which it not persist at all) why is name which you got is bad for you ?

Comment: you of course can get and drive letter, after open volume and query it for `IOCTL_MOUNTDEV_QUERY_DEVICE_NAME` and with this name query mount manager for `IOCTL_MOUNTMGR_QUERY_DOS_VOLUME_PATH` but i not sure are you really need this

Comment: The name I get is something like this:  ` \\?\USB#VID_0781&PID_5583#4C530000260829120162#{a5dcbf10-6530-11d2-901f-00c04fb951ed}` and I actually donot know how to use it to perform write operation using command  WriteFile() which requirs creating handle that needs drive path.

Comment: Ok thanks. Let me try IOCTL_MOUNTDEV_QUERY_DEVICE_NAME

Comment: tried to find about IOCTL_MOUNTDEV_QUERY_DEVICE_NAME and  IOCTL_MOUNTMGR_QUERY_DOS_VOLUME_PATH but cant find much documentation

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using [`GUID_DEVINTERFACE_VOLUME`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/guid-devinterface-volume) to register device notification.

A workaround(if the volume(s) of your USB belong to the new drive) is to use [`GetLogicalDrives`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getlogicaldrives) checking the changed unit mask, after the device arrived:

```
LRESULT message_handler(HWND__* hwnd, UINT uint, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    static DWORD current_unit_mask = 0;
    switch (uint)
    {
    //...
    case WM_CREATE: // the actual creation of the window
    {
        // you can get your creation params here..like GUID..
        LPCREATESTRUCT params = (LPCREATESTRUCT)lparam;
        GUID InterfaceClassGuid = *((GUID*)params->lpCreateParams);
        DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE NotificationFilter;
        ZeroMemory(&NotificationFilter, sizeof(NotificationFilter));
        NotificationFilter.dbcc_size = sizeof(DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE);
        NotificationFilter.dbcc_devicetype = DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE;
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(GuidDevInterfaceList); i++) {
            NotificationFilter.dbcc_classguid = GuidDevInterfaceList[i];

            HDEVNOTIFY dev_notify = RegisterDeviceNotification(hwnd, &NotificationFilter, DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE);
            if (dev_notify == NULL) {     // Handle the error by returning correct error in LRESULT format and remove throw...   
                throw std::runtime_error("Could not register for device Notifications!");
            }
        }
        current_unit_mask = GetLogicalDrives(); //Get the initial value
    }
    break;

    case WM_DEVICECHANGE:
    {

        PDEV_BROADCAST_HDR lpdb = (PDEV_BROADCAST_HDR)lparam;

        //DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME
        if (lpdb->dbch_devicetype == DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE)
        {

            switch (wparam)
            {

            case DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL:
            {
                cout << "Device Arrived" << endl;
                DWORD tmpmask = GetLogicalDrives();
                DWORD changed_mask = tmpmask ^ current_unit_mask; //changed_mask stores the uintmask of the changed device
                current_unit_mask = tmpmask; //update current_unit_mask

            }break;
            }
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Thanks @RbMm pointed out, the drive could have several volume, and a volume can be inserted without adding to a new drive.
So the logic above could be monitoring the changes of volumes:

```
#include <windows.h> 
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;
vector<wstring> GetVolumePaths(vector<wstring> volumes)
{
    DWORD  ReturnLength = 0;
    WCHAR Names[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
    PWCHAR NameIdx = NULL;
    BOOL   Success = FALSE;
    vector<wstring> VolumePaths;
    for (int i = 0; i < volumes.size(); i++)
    {
        for (;;)
        {
            Success = GetVolumePathNamesForVolumeNameW(volumes[i].c_str(), Names, MAX_PATH, &ReturnLength);

            if (Success)
            {
                break;
            }

            if (GetLastError() != ERROR_MORE_DATA)
            {
                break;
            }

        }
        if (Success)
        {
            for (NameIdx = Names;
                NameIdx[0] != L'\0';
                NameIdx += wcslen(NameIdx) + 1)
            {
                wprintf(L"  %s", NameIdx);
                VolumePaths.push_back(NameIdx);
            }
            wprintf(L"\n");
        }

    }
    return VolumePaths;
}
vector<wstring> GetDiff(vector<wstring> v1, vector<wstring> v2)
{
    vector<wstring> diff;
    std::sort(v1.begin(), v1.end());
    std::sort(v2.begin(), v2.end());
    std::set_difference(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end(),
        std::inserter(diff, diff.begin()));
    return diff;
}

vector<wstring> FindVolume()
{
    DWORD  CharCount = 0;

    DWORD  Error = ERROR_SUCCESS;
    HANDLE FindHandle = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    size_t Index = 0;
    BOOL   Success = FALSE;
    WCHAR  VolumeName[MAX_PATH] = L"";
    vector<wstring> volumes;

    FindHandle = FindFirstVolumeW(VolumeName, ARRAYSIZE(VolumeName));
    if (FindHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        Error = GetLastError();
        wprintf(L"FindFirstVolumeW failed with error code %d\n", Error);
        return volumes;
    }
    volumes.push_back(VolumeName);
    for (;;)
    {
        //
        //  Skip the \\?\ prefix and remove the trailing backslash.
        Index = wcslen(VolumeName) - 1;

        if (VolumeName[0] != L'\\' ||
            VolumeName[1] != L'\\' ||
            VolumeName[2] != L'?' ||
            VolumeName[3] != L'\\' ||
            VolumeName[Index] != L'\\')
        {
            Error = ERROR_BAD_PATHNAME;
            wprintf(L"FindFirstVolumeW/FindNextVolumeW returned a bad path: %s\n", VolumeName);
            break;
        }

        Success = FindNextVolumeW(FindHandle, VolumeName, ARRAYSIZE(VolumeName));
        if (!Success)
        {
            Error = GetLastError();
            if (Error != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES)
            {
                wprintf(L"FindNextVolumeW failed with error code %d\n", Error);
                break;
            }
            Error = ERROR_SUCCESS;
            break;
        }
        volumes.push_back(VolumeName);
    }

    FindVolumeClose(FindHandle);
    FindHandle = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    return volumes;
}


LRESULT message_handler(HWND__* hwnd, UINT uint, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    static vector<wstring> current_volumes;
    switch (uint)
    {
    //...
    case WM_CREATE: // the actual creation of the window
    {
        // you can get your creation params here..like GUID..
        LPCREATESTRUCT params = (LPCREATESTRUCT)lparam;
        GUID InterfaceClassGuid = *((GUID*)params->lpCreateParams);
        DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE NotificationFilter;
        ZeroMemory(&NotificationFilter, sizeof(NotificationFilter));
        NotificationFilter.dbcc_size = sizeof(DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE);
        NotificationFilter.dbcc_devicetype = DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE;
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(GuidDevInterfaceList); i++) {
            NotificationFilter.dbcc_classguid = GuidDevInterfaceList[i];

            HDEVNOTIFY dev_notify = RegisterDeviceNotification(hwnd, &NotificationFilter, DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE);
            if (dev_notify == NULL) {     // Handle the error by returning correct error in LRESULT format and remove throw...   
                throw std::runtime_error("Could not register for device Notifications!");
            }
        }
        current_unit_mask = FindVolume();
    }
    break;

    case WM_DEVICECHANGE:
    {

        PDEV_BROADCAST_HDR lpdb = (PDEV_BROADCAST_HDR)lparam;

        //DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME
        if (lpdb->dbch_devicetype == DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE)
        {

            switch (wparam)
            {

            case DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL:
            {
                cout << "Device Arrived" << endl;
                vector<wstring> tmp = FindVolume();
                vector<wstring> change_volumes = GetDiff(tmp, current_volumes);
                vector<wstring> VolumePaths = GetVolumePaths(change_volumes);
                current_volumes = tmp;
                for(int i = 0; i < VolumePaths.size(); i++)
                {
                    wprintf(L"   %s\n", VolumePaths[i]);
                }
            }break;
            }
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is not correct way, because can additional volume be inserted after this. drive can have several partitions/volumes. or can not have any at all

Comment: @RbMm Thanks for pointed out. It seems that OP wants to get volume drive letter. And I divide my USB into two volumes, `E:` and `F:`, the code also work for me. Did I miss understanding something?

Comment: can another device be inserted or removed before you call `GetLogicalDrives` than drive letter can be at all not assigned to device. this is not reliable way. correct way - (1) open device by *dbcc_name* (2) query it device name (*IOCTL_MOUNTDEV_QUERY_DEVICE_NAME*) and (3) query mount manager by device name (*IOCTL_MOUNTMGR_QUERY_DOS_VOLUME_PATH*). but first OP must ask another question and explain why he want exactly dos volume path (this is only one of several symbolic link names for device)

Comment: on detecting USB Arrival, I want to return the drive letter (c,d,e,...) of the USB device. This drive letter will be used to write raw bytes. For writing I have to create a handle which requires drive letter in the format \\.\drive_letter:

Comment: Are you able to use `GUID_DEVINTERFACE_VOLUME` and get a volume GUID path like "\\?\Volume{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}\" ?

Comment: Moreover when device is removed (DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE) I need to know whether the removed drive is the one in which I wrote. If I can get the drive letter when usb is inserted, I can use that drive letter to see if that drive is removed or some other drive is removed. On removal of a hardware I can check if the particular drive is still connected or not and call some functions based on it

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT Yes. I can get a path \\?....... something USB\\....

Comment: but I do not know how to extract drive letter from that information. And please note that I am a new coder and this is my first win32 program so i may be asking some silly/simple questions

Comment: The " \\?\USB#VID..." seems not a volume name. Just try the `NotificationFilter.dbcc_classguid = GUID_DEVINTERFACE_VOLUME;` in the `WM_CREATE` and remove others.

Comment: After using GUID_DEVINTERFACE_VOLUME, I get      \\?\STORAGE#Volume#{e2e94669-6804-11ea-aa99-b4a9fc221971}#0000000000100000#{53f5630d-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b}

Comment: First, are you able to get `DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212065/discussion-between-drake-wu-msft-and-mycopy).

Comment: Hi,@MyCopy, did the solution above solve your issue? Please feel free to let me know if you have any problem.